# WP_Editor not saving data in user_meta

Tags: user-meta, wp-editor

I have a front-end plugin which allows users to modify the fields (user_meta) of their profile, and everything works except the wp_editor.

```
           <div class="">
                <label class="" for="dokan-store-about"><?php _e( 'About Us', 'dokan' ); ?></label>
                <div class="dokan-text-left">
                   <?php
                    $content = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'wpcf-store-about', true);
                    $editor_id = 'dokan-store-about';
                    wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, array('textarea_name' => 'dokan-store-about') );

                    ?>
                    <textarea name="hey"><?php echo $content?></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and the saving part (which works for the image field, not for the wysiwyg)

```
$store_image = $_POST['dokan_store_image'];
    $store_about = $_POST['dokan-store-about'];
    $store_id = get_current_user_id();
    update_user_meta( $store_id, 'wpcf-store-image', $store_image );
    update_user_meta( $store_id, 'wpcf-store-about', $store_about );
```

As you can see i hardcoded a textarea with the same content, and if i save it like

```
update_user_meta( $store_id, 'wpcf-store-about', $_POST['hey'] );
```

it works fine.
So i don't see what is going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried logging all of the values in $_POST after the form submits to see how the data appears? It may not be getting set simply as $_POST['dokan-store-about'] like you expect.

Comment: This is not the information you are asking for, BUT:

There are some pretty serious security problems in your implementation here. Allowing someone to add anything they want into your database without any validation/sanitization exposes your site in a big way to being exploited.

recommended reading: [Validating Sanitizing and Escaping User Data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data)

Comment: Thank you Matt: about sanitizing I know..this is just a "testing" code and I will add the sanitizers later.

I tried to log both POST and the meta during the savin process and it doesn't work. It always shows the old one.

But if i press the button twice (submit button of the form) it does actually save it.

I'm confused

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
jQuery(‘input[name=dokan_update_profile]‘).click(function(){

tinyMCE.triggerSave();
});
```

Needed to update manually the tinymce, guess because it's in an Iframe.

Thanks anyway